# How do I count the number of occurences of a tag in json response in soup UI?using assertions

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

My json response

```
{
  "planList": [
    {
      "planCode": "xx",
      "statusCode": "0"
    },
    {
      "planCode": "yy",
      "statusCode": "0",
      "statusMessage": "Success"
    },
    {
      "planCode": "zz",
      "statusCode": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now i want to count the number of occurrences of `plancode`.

Comment: Is that what you want? def myJson = "your json response"
myJson.count("planCode")

Comment: I want to count it using assertions

Answer (score 0):

```
def json  = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText("""    {
      "planList": [
        {
          "planCode": "xx",
          "statusCode": "0"
        },
        {
          "planCode": "yy",
          "statusCode": "0",
          "statusMessage": "Success"
        },
        {
          "planCode": "zz",
          "statusCode": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
    """)

println json.planList*.planCode                 // all planCodes
println json.planList*.planCode.size()          // all planCodes' count
println json.planList*.planCode.unique()        // uniq planCodes
println json.planList*.planCode.unique().size() // uniq planCodes's count
```